# Filtro de models amarradas pelo Sequelize

Tags: javascript, sequelize-js

Eu tenho duas models na minha aplicação, Delivery e DeliveryProblem. DeliveryProblem tem uma PK (delivery_id) de Delivery:

```
static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.Delivery, {
      foreignKey: 'delivery_id',
      as: 'delivery',
    });
  }
```

Preciso selecionar todos as Deliveries que têm um DeliveryProblem. Meu método na controller está assim:

```
async index(req, res) {
    const response = await DeliveryProblem.findAll({
      order: ['id'],
      attributes: ['delivery_id'],
    });

    // Filtrando todos os ids de Encomendas que tenham algum problema
    const ids = [...new Set(response.map((x) => x.delivery_id))];

    const deliveries = Delivery.findAll({
      where: , // <<< Como filtrar os ids aqui ?
      order: ['id'],
    });

    return res.json(deliveries);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi da seguinte maneira, utilizando o Op do Sequelize:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const Op = Sequelize.Op
...
// Filter all Deliveries with problem
const ids = [...new Set(response.map((x) => x.delivery_id))];
const deliveries = Delivery.findAll({
  where: {
   id: {
     [Op.in]: ids
   }
  },
  order: ['id'],
});
```